# mysql COUNT(CASE) returns same results despite conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL query with several table joins. In one join I am trying to count the related records that have master_id as NULL.

There are 1146 total related records and no_master returns 1146 whereas it should return 0. I have tried BOTH of the following and BOTH return 1146 ... how can that be?

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ac.master_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'no_master'

COUNT(CASE WHEN ac.master_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'no_master'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUM`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ac.master_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'no_master'
<=>
SUM(ac.master_id IS NULL) AS 'no_master'
```

`COUNT` does not differentiate between 0 and 1.

---

If you want `COUNT` then you could use:

```
COUNT(ac.master_id)
-- by default COUNT omit `NULL` values
```

Comment: The spaceship operator (`<=>`) is there to tell us both SUM statements are the same? (translating for future readers)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, exactly ("<=> is equivalent of")